# TimeZone Issue with Http Parser

Tags: datetime, blackberry, timezone, dst, date-parsing

I am using the following BlackBerry Java code for parsing the Date by setting its time zone too.

The Default timezone is +01:00 Europe/Belgrade Yugoslavia(YU)

I am using the following code :

```
Date formatter11 = new Date(HttpDateParser.parse("2013-08-02T14:00:00+04:00"));
```

Output comes as :

```
Fri Aug 02 12:00:00 Europe/Belgrade Yugoslavia(YU) 2013
```

which is wrong . Please let me know the error why parsing is not been correct.
It comes as one hour extra .

Actually , I was concerned for DayLight event that happens with Blackberry phones  ... what is that issue .

Comment: Please let me know on Day Light Event in Blackberry

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "daylight event"?  I agree with Peter's answer below.  Do you need more explanation on his answer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure this is one hour extra?

The time seems to saying it is 14:00, and the time zone is UTC + 4 hours, So UTC time is 10:00, Yugoslavia is 1 hour ahead of that, plus daylight saving means 12:00.

Most likely I have missed something.

Comment: Hmmm .. please explain me on Daylight Event

Comment: Do these explain Daylight Saving?  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving or http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/europe-starts-dst-2013.html